# PySpark apply custom function on column

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to run a custom function on a dataframe column. The column has a long string, which contains some emails. The string format is something like this:

```
"Don Joe<abc@bankatfirst.com>,  Matt Scheurer <def@bankatfirst.com>, Dan Lawler <ghi@bankatfirst.com>"
```

I've to run regex to extract emails, then I've to find how many unique emails are there in the entire column.

I can write the regex and create unique emails list in python. But I don't know how to apply this function on spark dataframe. I tried doing something like this:

```
all_names = set()

def get_distinct_users(userlist):
    global all_names
    for email in re.findall('\<\S*\>',userlist):
        all_names.add(email)

get_distinct_users_udf = udf(get_distinct_users,StringType())
users = users.withColumn("user_count",get_distinct_users_udf(users["users"]))
```

But the gloabl variable all_names isn't getting updated. Should I apply map function instead of creating UDF, or maybe reduce because it is sort of an aggregation function?

Any idea?

Comment: Of course this isn't going to work.  Each executor gets its own copy of `all_names`; other executors cannot access it...

Comment: What if I make `all_names` an accumulator?

Comment: There is only [built in support](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators) for numeric types, but you could maybe make your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do this is to `flatMap` a function to extract a list of the email addresses over the column, e.g.,

```
import re

def get_email(x):
  return re.findall("\<\S*\>", x)

uniqueEmails = users.select("users").rdd\
  .flatMap(lambda x: get_email(x[0]))\
  .distinct()
```

will be an RDD of the distinct email addresses.